# How disable Paypal express checkout or require a shipping price

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-community, paypal-express

My problem is: When someones click on shopping cart and then click on paypal express checkout it goes to paypal page and no needs that the buyer select the shipping method neither select it itself...

So with that anyone can avoid shipping price. And I do not want that.

What can I do?

I see in some videos on youtube where people goes to paypal settings in magento and choses something like, send shipping information to paypal; but I do not have that configuration options only can set my paypal tokens.
I guess that is because my country is Portugal in settings.

My idea is disable ONLY paypal express and keep paypal standard. But I do not know how to do that...

And I have 2 shipping options: payment on delivery and paypal, and I want enable paypal only for courier (CTT Correios) shipping method and disable  for payment on delivery.

How can I do That 2 things?

---

[image: Payment Methods]

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue here is that this can only be turned on/off at a website level.

If you go to the admin config and select the website you want to turn off the express checkout then when you go to the Paypal Express configuration you will see the field `Enable this Solution`. Here you can set it as `No`, save the config and clear the cache then you should not see the express checkout option anymore.

[image: Paypal express configuration]

Comment: I don't see that configuration :(

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to see the setting that David Manners wrote about, to disable PayPal express:

1. go to system -> configuration -> Payment Methods
2. click configure button of PayPal Express Checkout
3. under Required Paypal Settings there is a section called Express Checkout - expand that and you'll see the "Enable this solution" setting that you can switch to "No" to disable it.

But as he said, you'll want to make sure that you've set the Current Configuration Scope to the website level that you want to apply this change to.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer to your question but to prevent paypal express checkout appear in your checkout, you have following option in Magento 1.9.2.2

1. go to `system -> configuration -> Payment Methods`
2. click `configure` button of `PayPal Express Checkout`
3. under `Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout` you will see following

[image]

4. select no for `Display on Product Details Page` and `Display on Shopping Cart`
5. click `save config` and clear cache